# How to build target by name in CMake?

Tags: c, cmake

I have cmake project that consist of multiple targets.

```
MyProject/
/target1
       /Some stuff
       /CMakeLists.txt // here add_executable(target1 main.c)
/target2
/target3
...
CMakeLists.txt // root CMakeLists.txt file
/build // folder for build files
```

I wand to build only target1 and put it into /build folder inside my project

I could build all targets

```
[MyProject/build]$ cmake ..
[MyProject/build]$ make
```

How to build only target1?

I guess it must be something like this?

```
[MyProject/build]$ cmake ..
[MyProject/build]$ cmake --build . --target target1 -- -j 12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you set an executable inside CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable( my_exe ${my_exe_sources} )
```

Then you can call `make my_exe -j 2`

Answer (score 1):

Your commands should work fine

```
cmake ..
cmake --build . --target target1 -- -j 12
```

will build `target1` and its dependencies only.